# WinRT/WP8 equivalent of System.Globalization.TextInfo.ToTitleCase

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

What's the WinRT/WP8 equivalent of [System.Globalization.TextInfo.ToTitleCase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase.aspx)?

Comment: Where are you planning to use this?

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why not, but it's not available in WinRT. There's a discussion on the [MSDN Forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/aca32898-c161-411b-bfbb-6631956aba2d/where-is-textinfototitlecase) about it that does include an replacement implementation.